# Can you change the properties of scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I need lights to stay "stationary" in my scene.  The best lighting method I've found so far is to actually to use `scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true` however, I can't figure out if there's any way to control some of the attributes.  The intensity of the light is a BIT too bright, the location of the light is a BIT different than where I'd like it to be, those kinds of properties.

I've tried using all sorts of other lights, coding them individually BUT since they add to the scene as nodes, the lights (in those cases) themselves will move when I set `scnView.allowsCameraControl = true`.  The default lighting is the only one that will remain "stationary" once the user begins to move the camera around.  Can you access/control the properties of the default lighting?

Comment: The trick here is to add your new lights to the camera node or a child of it. This way, when the camera moves, so too will the light. Try accessing the default camera node via [`scnView.pointOfView` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/pointOfView).

Comment: Make your lights a child of camera, make camera a child of root. Put your geometry nodes in a container, make that a child of root. Keep the geometry independent of the camera. (Never move root!) The default lighting and camera are rudimentary in options. It's better, and not that difficult, to create your own.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that a try!

Comment: @lock, @bpedit, OK, I just tried both of those and I'm still having the same problem.  First I made my light a child of the camera `cameraNode.addChild(Omnilight)`, while making the camera a child of the main scene, `scene.rootnode.addChild(cameraNode)`.  After all that, the `scnView.allowsCameraControl` still moves the scene around and the light moves with it.  I also tried accessing the point of view property, `scnView.pointOfView = cameraNode` and even though it doesn't flag for errors, the end result is the same!  Scene moves and light moves with it!!  Ideas??

Comment: `allowsCameraControl` is moving your entire scene. You need to manipulate, and view through, your `SCNCamera` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget `allowsCameraControl` and default cameras and lights if you want control of your scene.

```
let sceneView = SCNView()
let cameraNode = SCNNode()          // the camera
var baseNode = SCNNode()            // the basic model-root
let keyLight = SCNLight()       ;   let keyLightNode = SCNNode()
let ambientLight = SCNLight()   ;   let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()

func sceneSetup() {
    let scene = SCNScene()
    // add to an SCNView
    sceneView.scene = scene

    // add the container node containing all model elements
    sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(baseNode)

    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 50)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    keyLight.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    keyLightNode.light = keyLight
    keyLightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 10, y: 10, z: 5)
    cameraNode.addChildNode(keyLightNode)

    ambientLight.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    let shade: CGFloat = 0.40
    ambientLight.color = UIColor(red: shade, green: shade, blue: shade, alpha: 1.0)
    ambientLightNode.light = ambientLight
    cameraNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // view the scene through your camera  
    sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode

    // add gesture recognizers here
}
```

Move or rotate `cameraNode` to effect motion in view. Or, move or rotate `baseNode`. Either way, your light stay fixed relative to the camera.

If you want your lights fixed relative to the model, make them children of `baseNode` instead of the camera.

Comment: I am very curious about node positions, If you could explain how camera node z is 50 and Omni light position is go together it would be great

Answer (score 0):

If someone who wondering how to setup entire scene with new Scenekit integration with swift ui go though this. This work fine.

```
struct TestControllerNew: View {
    let sceneView = SCNView()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    var baseNode = SCNNode()
    let id = "D69A09F8-EA80-4231-AD35-4A9908B4343C"
    var scene = SCNScene()

    var body: some View {
        SceneView(
            scene: sceneSetup(),
            pointOfView: cameraNode,
            options: [
                .autoenablesDefaultLighting
            ]
            )
 
}
    
    func getTermsOfUseURL() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0].appendingPathComponent("\(id).usdz")
    }
    
    func sceneSetup() -> SCNScene {
        let scene = try! SCNScene(url: getTermsOfUseURL())
        // add to an SCNView
        sceneView.scene = scene

        // add the container node containing all model elements
        sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(baseNode)

        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)


        // view the scene through your camera
        sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode

        // add gesture recognizers here
        return scene
    }
}
```

Here the USDZ file get from document directory as a URL, you can use name instead of that.